# mocking super class protected method returns null for @Mock on class variables

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I am trying to write a unit test for a most common scenario.

```
class A{
  protected void m1() {
    //something
  }
}
//class A is from a different/external binary

class B extends A {
@Autowired Properties props
  public void m2() {
    //something
    if(props.getSomething()) {
      m1();
    }    
  }
}

class BTest {
  @Mock Properties props;

  @Test
  public void testM2() {
    MockB b = mock(MockB.class);
    doNothing().when(b).m1();
    when(b.m2()).thenCallRealMethod();
    when(props.getSomething()).thenReturn(1);
  }

  class MockB extends B {
   @Override
   public void m1() {
    return;
   }
  }
}
```

problem here is, as of now test is failing. When I tried debugging the test, I have observed null is being injected into **props** and this is causing NPE. When I remove class implementation from test, I can see props mock is working fine but it is failing at m1() call. Can someone please help me what I am missing here, I tried referring props with **MockB b** reference like **b.props** but this is also throwing NPE. Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you mock the class that under test?

Comment: I am using mock(MockB.class) so that I can doNothing()/return on protected method call,  please suggest for any changes. Was referring something like below
https://www.liatrio.com/blog/mocking

Comment: I dont want the actual execution to happen when the protected method executes, instead I want nothing or some mock value for my test

Comment: what is your objective to test the method, it is not clear from the code anyway added an answer

Answer (score 0):

I have used only mockito, You do not need the mock class, below should work

```
   class BTest {
        @Mock
        private Prop props;
    
        @Test
        public void testM2() {
            B bSpy = spy(new B(props));
            when(props.getSomething()).thenReturn(1);
            doNothing().when((A) bSpy).m1();
            doCallRealMethod().when(bSpy).m2();
            
            bSpy.m2();
        }
    }
```

If you use `super.m1()` this won't work

Comment: I am using PowerMock runner for my test. My bad that objective wasn't clear. My class under test  is calling super class protected method m1() in its method m2(). As the method is potected, I have extended test class in unit test so that I can mock/test super class protected method. But after the above changes,  the prop filed in the class under test is assigned to null even after it is mocked. Wanted to understand if this is because I have extended the class under test in test class and how can I include the props in MockB

Comment: @harishbollina please check, updated the answer

Comment: thanks for the edit, I am seeing two problems here, as m1() in super class is protected, casting and calling method still gives visibility error and props is autowired in B, so Mock should work, but after creating Mock class in test, I was able to mock the method but the props is coming null